# Find the Radius of Convergence of the Series $\sum a_{n}x^{n^{2}}$ Using $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to show that $$\sum a_{n}x^{n^2}$$ has radius of convergence of 1, using the fact that the power series $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$ has radius of convergence $R>1$, where $R$ is a real number (actually the problem says $R=2$).

I found out that this holds if $$\lim |a_{n}|^{1/n}= \dfrac{1}{R},$$ but I couldn't draw the same result using only that $\limsup |a_{n}|^{1/n}= \dfrac{1}{R}.$

Obviously the series converges at $x=1$, so its radius of convergence is at least 1, but how do I show that it's exactly $1$? I'm not even sure about it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check This ,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius)$\lim \sup|a_nx^{n^2}|^{1\over n}<1$ for convergence

Comment: Gee, thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The [radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) for
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
$$
is
$$
\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
The radius of convergence for
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n^2}
$$
is
$$
\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n^2}}
$$

Comment: How you get this $
\frac1{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n^2}}
$

Comment: @CloudJR: It doesn't matter what it is called, $a_n$ is the coefficient of $x^{n^2}$ and that is what [Cauchy-Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) cares about.